# How to link a variable to vertices of a directed graph using bubles with different sizes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

This `Code` produces a directed graph:

```
SeedRandom[12];
mat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {5, 5}];
select[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := matrix*Map[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] &, matrix, {-1}];
sa = SparseArray[select[mat, .1, .4]];
weightedG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

I like to attach a variable:

```
emp = {10, 45, 2, 1, 49};
```

to each vertex using bubbles with different sizes based on the variable `emp`, that is, the bubble size of vertex 1 should be a normalized size (i.e., 10/107), for vertex 2 (45/107), and so on. Elements of the variable `emp` are associated with five vertices {1,2,3,4,5}, respectively.

The final directed graph should be one with vertices of different bubble sizes.

Comment: Maybe with `VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> 
 Thread[Rule[Range[5], emp/Total[emp]]]' ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what: It worked, thank you very much. I will accept it if you give an answer.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what: When I change the range of `select[...]`, then the number of linkages and vertices also change. This change should be carried out in the selection of elements in `emp`. At present, the code works only for the digraph with 5 vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `emp` as the setting for `VertexSize`:

```
Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], 
 VertexSize -> {v_ :> ({#, #} & @ Normalize[emp, Total][[v]])},
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", (* so that arrow heads are not covered by vertex disks *) 
 ImagePadding -> 10, (* so that vertex labels are not clipped *)
 EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine but if you try `emp = {10, 45, 80, 1, 30, 90, 25, 20, 17, 39};  sa = SparseArray[select[mat, .1, .2]]`  I get an uncomfortable graph in which vertices are mixed up.!

Comment: also use this: `mat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 10}];`

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I think we need to set `VertexCoordinates` manually or use a layout like `GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"` to avoid vertex overlaps. You can also try `VertexSize -> {v_ :> {"Nearest",  Rescale[emp, MinMax@emp, {.5, .9}][[v]]}}`.

Answer (score 4):

With your definitions:

```
emp = {10, 45, 2, 1, 49};
normemp = Thread[Range[Length[#]] -> Normalize[#, Total]] &@emp;

ClearAll[f]
f[{x_, y_}, v_, {w_, h_}] := Disk[{x, y}, v /. normemp]

Graph[
 sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> f
]
```

[image: graph with circle labels with proportional sizes]